# The Rotten Tomatoes star rating in Google results

Tags: html, css, xhtml, meta, rotten-tomatoes

I would simply like to know how to display a star rating taken from individual pages to be displayed in google results ala rotten tomatoes or metacritic or imdb. If you search for 'Drive Rotten Tomatoes' in google it returns a link that also contains a rating % as well as Directed by and staring Actors links.

Where do i insert this information to have similar results. Does it go in the metadata for each page? How does it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Google rich snippets](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=146645) and [schema.org - Ratings](http://www.schema.org/Review)

Comment: Great! Thanks heaps for this. Very useful. Cheers. Pia @initall